# python script process stat stay on Sl and stop running

Tags: python, linux, process, kill

I run a python script and need to run a long time，but when I run a few hours it will stop，and I type `ps aux` the result is:

```
root     10371  0.9 10.4 273236 52232 ?        Sl   09:35   6:23 python my_programe.py
```

then I try to use `kill -18 10371` to call it , but useless, how can I continue to call it to run again?

Answer (score 0):

The process state `S` doesn't mean that the process has *stopped* (and thus trying to use SIGCONT to continue is of course useless), rather it means *Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)*. You should be able to see how long the process sleeps or what it waits for by using `strace -p`.